# Applying Update 4 for Visual Studio 2012 never ends

Tags: visual-studio-2012, updates

Today I have downloaded the Update 4 for Visual Studio 2012.
I have downloaded the file VS2012.4.exe from Microsoft website.
I have run this file from command line "VS2012.4.exe /layout". This has created the folder "Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 (KB2707250)" and inside this folder, there are a folder called "packages" and a file "VS2012.4.exe". I have run this exe file. 
The update process starts but, several hours later, the update process continue running.
The update process message is "Applying: KB2707250". The update takes several hours in this state.

Update:

The process is running and takes 4% of cpu (average).

Are there any people with the same behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you use the built in Tools --> Extensions and Updates menu item?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you have to specify a path when using the layout tag.

Comment: Same behavior. Think I need to download image file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue downloading the complete iso image twice. The first time, the iso was corrupt. 
The second time the iso was ok. I mount this iso and run the installation. The install process was right and it completes ok.

Thanks